# Paste Array to Range in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I am trying to build an array containing ranges using a loop so I can paste it all together to earn some time.
The loop pastes stock name from column L to another sheet. Then, dynamic values generate in range (CA59:CQ59).
I tried transpose function just in case, double loop for manual 2d array,and simpler ranges without luck. My best shot was something like

```
Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("O2:O" & UBound(pool) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(pool)
```

returned one column. Apologize for my lack of knowledge. Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Here is my code :

```
Sub ForecastAll()

Dim line As Range
Dim pool() As Variant
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 133
    Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("L" & i).Copy (Sheets("Stocks | Synopsis").Range("E3"))
    ReDim Preserve pool(i)
    pool(i) = Sheets("Stocks | Synopsis").Range("CA59:CQ59").Value  
Next i

 Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("O2:AE133").ClearContents
 Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("O2:AE133").Value = pool

End Sub
```

It returns blanks. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: If you want to learn about using arrays, this is a very good resource...https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#What_are_Arrays_and_Why_do_You_Need_Them

Comment: In your macro you are copying the same range with `pool(i) = Sheets("Stocks | Synopsis").Range("CA59:CQ59").Value`

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes in your code with explanation. Array populated from Worksheet column or row or table range values is a two dimensional array.

```
Sub ForecastAll()

Dim pool() As Variant
Dim i As Long

'clearing target range first to fill it with the loop below
Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("O2:AE133").ClearContents
For i = 2 To 133
    Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("L" & i).Copy (Sheets("Stocks | Synopsis").Range("E3"))
    ReDim Preserve pool(i)
    'pool(i) = Sheets("Stocks | Synopsis").Range("CA59:CQ59").Value
    'pool is one dimensional array where in at each iteration you are entering _
        'a two dimensional array. Which can be ensured with --
    'Debug.Print UBound(pool), Join(Application.Index(pool(i), 1, 0), ",")
    'instead of using an array you can directly assign values of one range to another like --
    Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("O2:AE" & i).Value = Sheets("Stocks | Synopsis").Range("CA59:CQ59").Value
    'This method should also work fast as it is not selecting ranges and copying-pasting values _
        'If you still want to use array, it should be a 2D array and it can not be populated directly _
        'from range and it will need a loop to populate that array

Next i

 'Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("O2:AE133").ClearContents
 'Sheets("Stocks | Sort").Range("O2:AE133").Value = pool

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns the same range every loop. However, I will take into consideration your advice. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @newbie .. In your macro you are copying the same range with `pool(i) = Sheets("Stocks | Synopsis").Range("CA59:CQ59").Value`.. I just corrected your code. If this answers your question, please consider voting/ accepting the answer.